# "eth0 not configured" but it was working earlier

Tags: networking

`sudo ifdown eth0` and `sudo ifup eth0` commands now give me `eth0 is not configured`.

These commands never gave me such answers earlier. I had changed the `/etc/network/interfaces` file earlier. But now replaced it with the original default one. now it is says `eth0 is not configured` and same for `wlano`. I am afraid to change any file. How to restore now?

Comment: Please provide content of interfaces file and output of 'ip link'

Comment: interfaces file has: Source -directory /etc/network/interface.d.                           ip link comman

Comment: ip link gives: eth0:<BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo-fast state up mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 link/ether 36:43:8a:f0:1f:5c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: sudo ifup eth0 gives "ignoring interface eth0 =eth0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it appears that, from your comments, that you have removed the loopback stanza from /etc/network/interfaces. It mustn’t be removed. Please amend the file to add back:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Next, ifup and ifdown are specifically reserved to manage interfaces which are declared and configured in /etc/network/interfaces. You have none. That is why you get the complaints when you issue the ifup command.

ifup eth0 is, roughly, shorthand for, “Bring up the interface found in /etc/network/interfaces which is declared as eth0.”

If you have removed eth0 and wlan0 from /etc/network/interfaces, then Network Manager should once again manage the interfaces. Restart NM:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: Actually after editing the interfaces file, and executing ifup command and rebooting the system,the networking icon at the right top disappeared.so I was worried what went wrong.then I changed the interfaces file as default one and rebooted the system.this time the networking icon (which signifies network manager I guess) stopped showing me "eth0" connection, wired connection etc. this is when I again gave ifup command and I got eth0 not configured message.i will give the command to restart the network manager.will I again get eth0 and wired connection in the edit connection icon?

Comment: You certainly should get the icon again. Did you try? If you are trying to up an interface that is *not* declared in interfaces, the correct command is: `sudo ifconfig eth0 up`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your. i get eth0 and wlan0 inthe networking icon right side.Now ubuntu i made as accesspoint.And receiving data wirelessly. but whenever i am connecting ethernet cable, ubuntu is not receiving any wifi data. This same set up used to work earlier before i changed the networking files. Can you help.

Comment: If my answer above has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour Your access point issue should be a new question which I see that you have already posted. I will see if I can help.

Comment: Tha k you so much. Do I need to do check or review anything in tour?

Comment: Just check how you may mark a useful answer as Accepted. If you feel that my answer above fits, please do so.

Comment: CAn you please anser the question asked "https://askubuntu.com/q/1061480/855548" This wil solve our application work here. Can you look into this?

Comment: Chili555 can you help in the question posted afresh?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reboot the machine if you didn't and if you have a downtime.

```
shutdown -r now
```